# Does unprotecting a question bump it to the front page?

Tags: support, protected-questions, bump

I did quite some research but didn't find a post or FAQ that explained that detail.

I ask this because, in case it does bump it, *wouldn't that make the question a target for noisy/shallow answers from new users again?* Although, I also suppose that bumping it is the only way for other users to find about it again, but as you can see I am caught in this dichotomy.

This is the reason why I didn't unprotected a post just to find out if it does, as this makes me unsure how to properly handle an carry out an effective unprotection.

I already read the FAQ and other posts, but do you have *any other tips and insights you think are good for an effective protecting/unprotecting?*

Comment: Also, with regards to your last question, see this blog post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/08/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/

Comment: From what I can tell, there are three questions. The first is answered in the duplicate as *no*. The second is moot because it only applies if the answer to the first was *yes*, which it wasn't. The third is answered in the blog post I linked.

Comment: @Sonictheinclusivehedgehog perhaps you would care condensing those sources into an answer? :) thank you for the links anyways

Comment: @DarkCygnus no, a question on SE should contain only one single question. If you ask more, then it should be closed as too broad anyway.